# Div appears to remove from the center when viewed on larger screen

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a section of my home page that when viewed in screen sizes other than the one I am working on, it changes position. I think it is to do with the position element but I am not sure exactly what it should be set to or where it should be placed within my CSS.

The section I want remaining in the same place is a jquery image transition which is shown below the navigation menu within the image. See HTML and CSS below aswel for further reference.

Thank you for any help guys

[image]

```
HTML:

<body>
<div id="top_bar">
<div id="top_inner">
<div id="logo"> <a href="http://www.edosbornephotography.com"><img src="images/logo.gif" alt="Ed Osborne" width="225" height="115" class="logo"></a></div>
<div class="nav">
<ul class = "menu" >
            <li> <a href = "#" > Home </a> </li>
            <li><a href = "#" > Packages </a>
            <li><a href = "#" > Weddings </a>
            <li><a href = "#" id="left" > Lifestyle </a>
        <ul class = "submenu" >
            <li> <a href = "#" > Families </a> </li>
            <li> <a href = "#"> Newborn/Child </a> </li>
            <li> <a href = "#" > Portraits </a> </li>
        </ul>
        </li>

        <li> <a href = "#" > Blog </a> </li>
        <li><a href = "#" id="left"> Abous Us </a>
        <ul class = "submenu" >
        <li> <a href = "#" > Ed Osborne </a> </li>
        <li> <a href = "#" > Testimonials </a> </li>
        <li> <a href = "#" > FAQs </a> </li>
        </ul>
        </li>

        <li> <a href = "#" > Contact Us </a> </li>
        <li> <a href = "#" > Links </a> </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<div id="main">  

<div id="smart-gallery">
    <a href="images/cubagallery-img-1.jpg">
        <img src="images/cubagallery-img-1.jpg" /></a> 

    <a href="images/cubagallery-img-15.jpg">
        <img src="images/cubagallery-img-15.jpg" /></a> 

    <a href="images/cubagallery-img-3.jpg">
        <img src="images/cubagallery-img-3.jpg" /></a> 

    <a href="images/cubagallery-img-4.jpg"></a>
        <img src="images/cubagallery-img-4.jpg" /></a>
</div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
#top_bar {
width: 100%;
height: 145px;
background: #000000;
padding-bottom: 20px;
}

#top_inner {
text-align: center;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 1000px;
height: 144px;
}

.nav {
margin: 0 auto;
position: relative;
padding-top: 100px;
}

ul.menu {
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
float: left;
background: #222;
font-size: 1.2em;
background: url(../images/topnav_bg.gif) repeat-x;
}

ul.menu li {
float: left;
margin: 0;  
position: relative; 
}

ul.menu li span { 
width: 11px;
height: 35px;
float: left;
background: url(../images/subnav_btn.gif) no-repeat center top;
}

.min-gallery
{
width: 927px;
height: 615px;
border: solid 1px black;
background-color: Black;
background: url(../images/bg.jpg);
margin: auto;
margin-left: 232px;
}

.min-gallery .preview
{
width: 852px;
height: 493px;
margin-top: 36px;
margin-left: 36px;
margin-right: 36px;
position: relative;
border: solid 2px black;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: White;
}

.min-gallery .preview img
{
width: 795px;             
height: 525px;
position: absolute;
}

.min-gallery .bottom
{
width: 100%;
height: 98px;
color: Gray;
font-family: Arial;
font-size: 1em;
font-weight: bold;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Might you have an url to share? cannot really see/figure it out without seeing it live.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add image. See image please

Comment: Still, the javascript does not execute so we don't have the final HTML code.  not really helpfull. Here is what we can work with: http://jsfiddle.net/FdpFW/

Comment: But I have explained the issue. The jquery image transition part loses its position either to the right or left when displayed on larger or smaller screens

Comment: @user1278496 Are we right to assume that the jquery part that you are refering to manipulates the `#smart-gallery`? If so then you need to provide the relative CSS. At the moment the HTML and CSS that has been provided seems too much and irrelevant (except the `#smart-gallery` html). Cutting the code down as much as possible and building an example that reproduces the problem is the easiest way to find the cause of an issue.

Comment: We only got the HTML of smart-gallery but no css. Only that of .min-gallery. so obviously the javascript changes the HTML. Without the final code we can't really debug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You html code does not contain any element with `min-gallery` class... but if you change it min-gallery with smart-gallery:

```
.smart-gallery
{
    width: 927px;
    height: 615px;
    border: solid 1px black;
    background-color: Black;
    background: url(../images/bg.jpg);
    margin: auto;
    margin-left: 232px; <- remove
}
.smart-gallery...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use percentages rather than pixels to position the gallery. A better way would be to use css media queries, so as the window changes so does the size and placement of your div.

There is not enough info here for me to write any pseudo code, and I couldn't load your site. But the following sites should get you started in the right direction.

[Quick tips a crash course in media queries](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/quick-tip-a-crash-course-in-css-media-queries/)

[Adaptive layouts](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/adaptive-layouts-media-queries)